# Fazendo replace ou append em um <p>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estava tentando fazer um **append** ou **replace** em jQuery de um HTML, mas não estou tendo êxito no mesmo. Ele substitui apenas um dos `<p>` que contém a classe `.frete-gratis` mas queria substituir todas por um `iframe`.

Segue o código que estou tentando fazer funcionar atualmente:

```
var $wrapper = document.querySelector('.frete-gratis'),
// Pega a string do conteúdo atual
HTMLTemporario = $wrapper.innerHTML,
// Novo HTML que será inserido
HTMLNovo = '<iframe allowtransparency="true" src="http://aws.glamour.com.br/quero_bazar/flag-counts/index.html" height="20" width="140"></iframe>';

// Concatena as strings colocando o novoHTML antes do HTMLTemporario
HTMLTemporario = HTMLNovo + HTMLTemporario;

// Coloca a nova string(que é o HTML) no DOM
$wrapper.innerHTML = HTMLTemporario;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com jQuery pode usar o método [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) (para adicionar no início do(s) elemento(s)) ou [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) (para adicionar no final):

```js
  // var é para variável ser local, não criando uma variável global tendo a possibilidade de dar conflito com outras bibliotecas.
  var HTMLNovo = '<iframe allowtransparency="true" src="http://aws.glamour.com.br/quero_bazar/flag-counts/index.html" height="20" width="140"></iframe>';
$('.frete-gratis').prepend(HTMLNovo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frete-gratis">DIV1: </div>
<div class="frete-gratis">DIV2: </div>
<div class="frete-gratis">DIV3: </div>
<div class="frete-gratis">DIV4: </div>
```

Comment: Legal man, funcionou aqui muito bom, mas não entendi o por que o código anterior estava pegando apenas o primeiro elemento setado, hahaha mais valeu mesmo !

Comment: @JulioSantos, o porquê é explicado na resposta do Zuul. ;)

Answer (score 5):

<sup>**Nota:** Não estás a fazer uso de jQuery mas sim a trabalhar com JavaScript puro e duro.</sup>

Estás a fazer uso do método [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) que te devolve apenas o primeiro elemento encontrado:

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.

Que traduzido:

> Retorna o primeiro elemento dentro do documento (usando a profundidade-primeiro pré-encomenda travessia de nós do documento) que coincide com o grupo especificado de seletores.

O que tu procuras é o método [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) que te devolve uma lista de elementos:

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

Que traduzido:

> Retorna uma lista dos elementos dentro do documento (usando a profundidade-primeiro pré-encomenda travessia de nós do documento) que correspondem ao grupo especificado de seletores. O objeto retornado é um NodeList.

O teu código ficaria assim:

```
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.frete-gratis');

[].forEach.call(wrappers, function(wrap) {

  // fazer o que pretendes, por exemplo mudar a cor
  wrap.style.color = "red";
});
```